# Most effective classroom management plan

Tags: secondary-education, classroom-management, syllabus

I'm looking for an effective classroom management plan for high school teachers. Mine is:

- Every student should have a notebook and a pen to take notes.
- Food, drinks, chewing gums and electronic devices are not allowed in the classroom. If you want to drink you should bring your water bottle with you.
- You can't joke or act like a clown.
- Every student should be sitting at his table when the teacher enters the classroom.
- You can't leave your place without permission.
- I won't tolerate cheating and plagiarism.

I give it to students on the first day of school. It's a part of the syllabus together with the table of contents, the evaluation schema, the objectives, the materials needed and the methodology.

I'm waiting to see some other classroom management plans, a more exhaustive one.

Comment: Is this specific to mathematics in any way?

Comment: @JW It's specific to educators.

Comment: Have you considered rules for calculators, or are they not permitted as electronic devices?

Comment: @JW They are allowed. I mention this in the materials (pen, ruler, calculator...).

Comment: You said pen and notebook. No mention of ruler or calculator. Given the range of calculators available, it's important to specify what's allowed if any. By the way, did you really mean pen? Most math teachers prefer students to use pencils.

Comment: I discuss calculators in the materials section in the syllabus. I accept non programmable calculators only because programmable calculators are forbidden in official exams.

Comment: And just to be clear. I'm getting the impression your goal is not a critique of your plan, but rather for interested parties to share theirs? I ask because I'm tempted to comment on the "no joking" clause...

Comment: @pjs36 I didn't post this (risky) question to share my plan. I find it weird that a site for educators doesn't discuss any management plan. I posted my sample plan to hear the ideas of other (high school) educators. Since there isn't any other SE site for educators and since I'm a mathematics educator, I posted it here.

Comment: Before you embark upon this course of action consider what you'll be able to effectively manage.  Ask what will I do when student X doesn't comply with rule y? Personally I think some of your rules are likely to lead to unessessary conflict. No joking? Why? I think you'll gain more respect by being yourself  having reasonable boundaries.

Comment: @Karl That's exactly why I want to hear what experienced educators have to say. I usually don't have to follow the management plan because the students like me and the way I teach but I curious how others manage their classrooms and what set of consequences they follow if someone break one of the rules. Also I spent a lot of time thinking about this plan when I was a new teacher (years ago) and maybe this question will help future teachers.

Comment: There are many factors to consider.  How old are the pupils?  What policies does the school have already?

Comment: @Karl They are high school students (15-18) as I mentioned above. Don't you use any management plan?

Comment: I have just spent about a half hour of my time crafting a respectful and disagreeing response to this post.  The thought briefly crossed my mind that this was an elaborate troll, and now reading the comments above, the thought has once again crossed my mind.  I will stop short of calling this post a troll, and give it some respect.  I caution the poster though that things do not look good, and that something needs to change if the poster hopes to get what he wants.  Gerhard "Has He Gotten It Already?" Paseman, 2015.07.26

Comment: I would suggest reading about **classroom norms** (sometimes generated by students themselves). Banning joking and "leaving one's place without permission," all within the syllabus, seems to adopt the position of martinet before teacher. (Rhetorically, as already commented: What is your plan for e.g. a student who jokes?) I don't know if your post fits in here, but at least look up **norms**...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It has nothing to do with teaching math, it's asking how to maintain discipline in the classroom.

Comment: I voted to close as off topic but think it would be appropriate to ask in the Academia SE site.

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate for academia, as it asks about managing a classroom of high school students.  Judging from the original posters comments, it seems more about crowd control than education.  It might be appropriate for a productivity or management forum.  As Joe Taxpayer notes, it has nothing to do with teaching math.  Gerhard "Not Seeing The Education Connection" Paseman, 2015.07.26

Comment: I teach in a high-needs public high school, and I also have similar questions about classroom management practices specific for math class. The points from the OP seem obvious in a university setting, but they are not obvious to my students, and I do similarly struggle with communicating these expectations. But since this question is on hold, I will haphazardly answer for now that the best classroom management tool that I have found so far is the implementation of [**Interactive Notebooks**](http://mathequalslove.blogspot.com/2015/05/q-time-management-with-interactive.html) (as a glimpse).

Comment: @XiYu I think most of the negative reaction to this question came from people who don't teach in schools or teach in schools in Utopia. Be realistic people, in some schools ALL teachers (even the ones that have a very good teaching style) spend a significant fraction of their time in class to manage disturbing students (talking, joking, sleeping..).  I don't have these problems right now but I had a tons of them when I began teaching. This post is more for new teachers than for me. And if the moderators don't want to feel the difficulties teachers face in some school,just delete this question.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to revise the question to make the math-classroom aspect more explicit or specific?

Comment: I think the question is in principle reasonable. But I would prefer you provide some more details in the post. For example,  I think the age of the students is quite crucial, as is the general context (maybe use the [tag:usa] if it applies; the standards and problems in  Argentina, Finland, Kenya, Philippines, Mongolia etc could be quite different, or not, but it makes the q very broad)  to this type of question. (It is in a comment but it should be in the body.) If possible, try to make it a bit more specific to math. Finally, a more direct question could help.

Comment: I now realize the age is maybe more explicit in the post than I realize as high-school is shorter than I thought.

Comment: High school age in the UK is 11 -16.

Comment: US high school is grade 9-12, approx age 14-18

Comment: I think the range in most countries is (14-15) to (17-18).

Comment: I suggest you look at Ron Clark's book, The Essential 55. This book is the comprehensive plan of an elementary school teacher and his success with it. Although you are thinking about high school, I believe you can find inspiration and ideas.

Comment: @AmyB I was putting this book on my reading list until I saw the [negative comments](http://www.amazon.com/review/RJ4BWV67S7Q5E/ref=cm_cr_dp_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0786888164&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=283155&store=books#wasThisHelpful) by teachers.

Comment: I read the book and got something out of it - and thought he showed himself to be a caring excellent teacher (but no one is perfect). You might check out this [summary](http://educatorsthinkspace.wikispaces.com/The+Essential+55) or [Education World](http://www.educationworld.com/a_issues/chat/chat073.shtml)  You might be surprised.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose I invite you to dinner.  I want you to have the best experience possible.  So I will manage things to maximize what I think is this best
experience.

Of course, everyone needs a place setting.  So I prepare name cards so that
you sit at your assigned place.  I think I know best who you will like to
talk to, so please stay in your seat during dinner.

I think the food should be served in a particular order.  So everyone needs to enjoy the same course at the same time. Of course, wasting food is sinful (or socially unacceptable) so we will wait until everyone finishes their course before moving on to the next.  You may have water at anytime, but the wine/beverage only does best with certain courses.  Please don't drink the wine except during those courses.

Of course, we want to observe proper table manners.  My apologies if you are left-handed (or single handed), please use the knife and spoon with the right hand and the fork with the left.  We don't want confusion or delay, and keeping diversity to the minimum should enhance everyone's experience, right?

Of course people will need to attend to (ahem) personal matters.  There will be restroom breaks between the fourth and fifth courses (not during the fourth course), and between the twelfth and thirteenth courses (not during the twelfth course).  A bell will ring to remind you at the appropriate time.  Please return to your seats for the beginning of the next course, so that there is no delay.

Regarding discussion, preferably only one person speaks at a time, and every one should pay attention to that person.  We will have a microphone-shaped marker to pass around; you will be briefed on its use at the beginning of dinner.  The list of topics to talk about will be on the green sheet; the areas to avoid on the red.  Don't confuse them!

...

I could go on, but what I have just done in my enthusiasm to do well is going to turn out to be a recipe for disaster.  People will either be too frightened or resentful to contribute, or you will spend too much time attempting to enforce conformity.  People will not remember how the food tasted or how delightful and edifying the dinner conversation was; they will remember the farce of attempted "experience management" that you hosted.

This is directly inspired by imagination and by your list.  In my (not so humble) opinion, you are concocting a plan for failure.

I agree that certain behaviour is encouraged in a classroom, that there should be rules, that to get things done in an effective fashion and not waste anyone's time, there should be a plan and guidelines.  Indeed you should have such a list.  However, if you are upfront and promoting the list before the material, I think you are not educating;  I think you are (attempting to be) controlling.

There are ways to achieve similar goals, but using a different approach.  Show students that this is a relaxed and inviting atmosphere, encourage certain values by actions and behaviour, recruit others to help this encouragement along, teach by modelling, and be forgiving about departures and mistakes.  This can encourage confidence as well as the desire to learn.  In my view, your list does not do that.

Of course, I'm not in your shoes, and I don't know what your agenda really is.  There are situations where your list might be ideal.  Certainly I don't disagree with some of the intent behind having such rules.  Just remember how easily dinner can go bad, regardless of how first-rate the food and drink are.

Gerhard "Class Over.  Time For Snack." Paseman, 2015.07.26

Comment: I was hoping we would hear from Gerhard "No Burping, No Slurping" Paseman :)

Comment: Most things come to them that wait.  Gerhard "Get The Zen Of It" Paseman, 2015.07.27

Comment: With all due respect, I think you've taken this analogy too far. You're comparing inviting people to dinner to teaching teenager students a subject that has a bad reputation among them and their parents! There may be some interested students in the class, some who don't care a lot and others who are at school just to have fun. It's YOUR responsibility to make sure that those disturbing students don't affect you, the other students and the atmosphere in your class.

Comment: Cont'd: I've seen a physics teacher with a PhD who quit the job after one week, I've seen some good students failing in a math class because they couldn't concentrate having very disturbing students near them (incidentally, the teacher was explaining everything clearly, but didn't have a management plan so things went down very fast for him and soon enough this teaching position was like a nightmare for him).

Comment: @metacompactness a PhD is irrelevant to managing a class.  When you say the teacher was explaining everything clearly what do you mean? What does explaining entail? In whose eyes was it clear? I think there are many valid discussion points that are being raised here and I believe I could contribute in a positive way to that discussion but stack exchange is better suited to less opinion based topics.

Comment: @Karl The teacher was very good. How do I know? I (and many other teachers) attended his class. What if students opinion were different? Well, According to most students (and to students he tutored), he was good but couldn't manage a class with disturbing students. I hope you get my point now. We could discuss education and theories endlessly but when you work on the ground with such students, you'll change your viewpoint.

Comment: I currently teach in a selective area of the UK. As a consequence the school has a disproportionate number of SEN students (effectively they have failed an exam already to go to a grammar school).

Comment: @metacompactness , no, I am trying to compare a teacher who wants to do their job well with a host that wants to do their job well.  Based on no other information than what you gave (e.g. no mention of behaviorial problems, low-motivated students, poor teaching conditions) I arrived at the cautionary tale above.  Even if you elaborate on your situation, I stand by my answer (but note the last paragraph): setting up a focus on following the rules detracts from focusing on the subject.  It may be necessary, but can be carried too far.  Gerhard "How Far? I Don't Know." Paseman, 2015.07.28

Comment: May I respectfully point out that there is still no reference to mathematics?  Although your comment about "a subject that has a bad reputation" points a finger, it helps to be more explicit.  If you had instead posted a question that says: "I'm a math teacher in (location) teaching (grade) and have a few disruptive students.  I want to know about management protocols...", and followed with your list, I would have treated your question with more respect and answered differently.  I urge you to be more clear with your questions.  Gerhard "Clarity Above Brevity And Wit" Paseman, 2015.07.08

Comment: This question is for all educators not just mathematics educators but since there's educators.SE.com site I had to post it here. As I mentioned in a comment above, I usually don't have to follow the management plan because the students like me and the way I teach but I curious how others manage their classrooms and what set of consequences they follow if someone break one of the rules. Also I spent a lot of time thinking about this plan when I was a new teacher (years ago) and maybe this question will help future teachers.

Comment: And whether you take this question seriously or not is your own opinion. I doesn't represent the opinion of teachers (especially the ones who struggle with students discipline everyday). My aim is to see management plans of experienced teachers in one page so that some teachers won't have to spend hours browsing the web to collect unreliable plans written by unknown people. If you want to contribute in a positive way you can update your answer; otherwise, let some other members contribute with their answers. And I still didn't get the `Gerhard "something here" Paseman, date` thing.

Comment: When the question is modified so that it is appropriate for the forum (at present some other of the forum community besides me has decided the question right now is not), then I will expand upon my answer.  It is your opinion that the question helps teachers; it is my (and perhaps it is others) opinion that it does not.  There are ways to ask that are helpful to others and will also achieve your goal, AND be accepted on this forum.  I hope you find one of those ways.  Gerhard "I Call It A Signature" Paseman, 2015.07.28

Comment: I agree with Gerhard and cast the first 'close' vote. His analogy is only flawed to the extent that all analogies are flawed, no more, no less. But it makes a point, the focus on discipline can distract from the intent of good teaching. Be in your seat on time? Sure. But when a girl has to race from one end of a huge building to the other to get to class and gets her period that day, I'll ignore the rules, not ask any questions, and gain her respect for my understanding. Too many rules are just that. Too many.